# VBA - Compile error: User defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, settings, defined

I attached macro to the button to copy data from one report to another. I am getting an error:
Compile error: User - defined type not defined.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4FQz.png)]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhIXq.png)

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim fs As FileSystemObject

Dim srcBK As Workbook
Dim trgBK As Workbook


Set fs = New FileSystemObject

Dim i As Long
i = 2
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""

    If Not (fs.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("A" & i).Value)) Then
        MsgBox "Source File " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("A" & i).Value & " does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf Not (fs.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("D" & i).Value)) Then
    
        MsgBox "Target File " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("D" & i).Value & " does not exist"
    
        
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set srcBK = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("A" & i).Value)
        Set trgBK = ThisWorkbook
        srcBK.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("B" & i).Value).Select
        
        srcBK.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("B" & i).Value).Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("C" & i).Value).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
        trgBK.Activate
        trgBK.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("E" & i).Value).Select
    trgBK.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("E" & i).Value).Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MACRO").Range("F" & i).Value).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        trgBK.Save
        
        
        srcBK.Close savechanges:=False
        
    
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
MsgBox "Copying Done"


End Sub
```